# Isn't "not detailed enough" a valid reason for answer deletion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Each time that I see a low quality post in the review queue, and have clicked "Recommend Deletion" for an answer, I am baffled by the options I am given to explain why.

First of all, the vast majority of the time, the answer is too short and doesn't explain well (or at all) any details of how it comes to its conclusion. Also, many of those times, the answer does not fully answer the question(s) posed.

However, "Needs more detail" (or anything similar) is simply not an option. Amazingly, the first (and auto-selected) option is "Needs no explanation," which a large part of me thinks should be removed. If you are voting to delete something, you always need a reason.

For some of the options there, I have never once seen a post that could use that option, so I wonder if they are needed at all.

Can we customize this part of the site for Puzzling? If so, what is the best way to make suggestions for that?

Comment: I think the 'Needs no explanation' flag is there for things like spam, insults, vulgar language, etc. I agree that I'd be a lot more comfortable suggestion deletions of posts that need more detail if I could flag them as such.

Comment: If  'Needs no explanation' is there for things like spam, insults, vulgar language, then let's replace it with "spam, insults, vulgar language"

Comment: Good idea! Custom close-vote reasons are certainly possible (e.g. the "maths problem not maths puzzle" one here), so I imagine custom delete-vote reasons are too. Maybe the [feature-request] tag?

Comment: I often use "no comment needed" when the post is blatantly inappropriate or low-quality.

Comment: The reason "needs no explanation" exists is mostly because oftentimes, six people review a post, and if all six are forced to leave a comment, it would be rather annoying to the answerer. I'll ask if it's customizable, because I agree - that would make more sense; sadly, I don't think it is.

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, I agree that a lot of different comments would be very annoying. I see the need to categorize as much as possible. Therefore, we really need categories that make sense.

Comment: @Emrakul If two reviewers select the same reason, is it posted twice? If so, I think a better behaviour would be an automated "upvote" of that comment.

Comment: @BmyGuest I could've sworn that the automated upvote is actually what happens. In any case, I remember that coming up in meta.SE a while back.

Comment: It is. We should add that option IMO.

Comment: Can we talk about this again? Because I'm always at a loss if I should skip or recommend deletion for 1-2 worded answers.